# How can I run this example of webpy?

Tags: python, web.py

I wrote this program:

```
import web

urls = (
    '/(.*)', 'hello'
)
app = web.application(urls, globals())

class hello:        

    def GET(self, name):
        if not name: 
            name = 'World'
        return 'Hello, ' + name + '!'

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

and ran it. It didn't have any errors and gave this address "`http   ://0.0.0.0:8080`", but when I open this page it says :

> """Unable to connect
>
> Firefox can't establish a connection to the server at 0.0.0.0:8080."""

Comment: `0.0.0.0` is probably the listening address ("all interfaces" in this case). Try connecting to `localhost` (`127.0.0.1`) instead.

Answer (score 0):

This might be of some help:

1. Clicks windows button then type 'Internet options' Go to Internet
   options and set the options correctly . Then you should be able to
   install the packages
   ( Previously I used to get this error, I used one internet settings in browser and other in internet explorer(the shell takes internet settings from here) .So after changing the default internet settings I am able to install the packages )
2. Now in firefox go to Options > Advanced > Network > Settings in
   the box No Proxy for : add the following (This ste localhost,
   127.0.0.1,0.0.0.0
3. run the file server.py Now go to localhost:8080 in browser instead
   of 0.0.0.0:8080 You should be able to see webpage containing 'None'

Firefox can't establish a connection to the server at 0.0.0.0:8080.

http://forums.udacity.com/questions/100063533/firefox-cant-establish-a-connection-to-the-server-at-00008080